# Highlight a cell if a corresponding cell (in another sheet) has a value in it

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

I am trying to compare pages of employee hours verses sales.  In order to catch myself if I record sales and not hours, I'd like the hours cell for a given date to highlight itself, if the sales cell has a value.

Here's an example of the "hours" sheet:

```
                2-Nov   3-Nov   4-Nov
Smith   Judy    0.8     7.25    0
```

And an example of the "totals" sheet:

```
               2-Nov     3-Nov   4-Nov
Smith   Judy   $15.72    $76.55  $82.13
```

The problem would be that Judy is listed as selling $82.13 (E2) in product, while having worked 0 hours (E2) according to the "hours" sheet.

Is there a conditional formatting formula that I can use to get Excel to highlight the "0" listed under 4-Nov on "Hours"?

Comment: Do the cell line up?  totals B2 is tied to hours B2.

Comment: Condition formatting formula `=And(E2>0,totals!E2 =0)`

Comment: Sorry formula wrong just read the last part `=And(E2=0, totals!E2>0)` I had it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a conditional formatting formula that I can use to get Excel to highlight the "0" listed under 4-Nov on "Hours"?

Yes.  If you want to highlight the "0" on the "Hours" sheet, you can use conditional formatting where the formula includes a reference to a cell on a different sheet.

For example, click on the Hours sheet cell E2.  Go to Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format and paste a formula in the "**Format values where this formula is true:**" box there, like:

```
And(E2>0,totals!E2 =0)
```

Then click the Format button below it on the right, activate the Fill tab, and click what color you want the cell to be highlighted in.

---

Thanks to Scott Craner's comment on the question for providing an improved formula.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just formatting a singe cell, I suggest selecting all the relevant columns in hours (presumably starting with C) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(OR(C1="",C1=0),NOT(ISBLANK(totals!C1)),NOT(ISBLANK($B2)))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of highlighting OK, OK.

This warns even when blank rather than `0` in `hours` but relies on names such as `Judy` to avoid extending to empty rows. It also allows for values in `totals` of nil or negative (in case of adjustments).